# Spring batch meta data tables in mongo database

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I tried to have spring batch meta data tables in Mongo database but its not working correctly. I referred and used below mentioned github project to configure JobRepository to store job data in Mongodb. This GitHub project is updated last 3 years ago and looks discontinued.

https://github.com/vfouzdar/springbatch-mongoDao
https://jbaruch.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/integrating-mongodb-with-spring-batch/

Currently my application uses in-memory tables for spring batch and functional part is done. But I want job data to be stored in Mongodb.
I have already used Mysql for spring batch job data but in current application don't want mysql.

If anybody has any other solution/link which can help me, please share.

Comment: Why do you want to use MongoDB? It's not transactional and the job repository should be transactional to be useful.

Comment: Saying **but its not working correctly** is not enough. What specific issues you face?

Comment: @SabirKhan Fields of JobExecution collection/table are not updated correctly. 
I am facing are below mentioned Problems:
1. JobInstance collection remains empty.
2. StepExecution collection remains empty.
3. status field in JobExecution remains STARTED even when Job is executed successfully
4. Job Id gets reset to One after server restart.
5. Job parameters are not stored in MongoDB.

Comment: Also facing below issues:

6. Record inside ExecutionContext collections is a below :
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59391d1aaf8809dc540a7911"),
    "stepExecutionId" : 1,
    "batch{dot}taskletType" : "org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet",
    "batch{dot}stepType" : "org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep"
}

Comment: @MichaelMinella Our application is using MongoDB for storing application data. We don't want to Spring batch data to be InMemory and also don't want to maintain MySQL just for spring batch data. Thats why was trying to store spring batch meta data in MongoDB

Comment: I could fix below issues by using SimpleMongoJobRepository properly:
3. status field in JobExecution remains STARTED even when Job is executed successfully 
4. Job Id gets reset to One after server restart.
But still other issues are open.

Comment: Does it work for you? I would like to have similar solution for Cassandra.